# How to assemble a file full path when both the dir path and the file name are variables?

Tags: perl

I have a perl script that get's 2 dir names, and go through all the files in the first dir, and find them at the second dir (and do some proccesing there).

the following:

```
opendir( SourceDir,  $first_dir);
my @files = readdir(SourceDir);
foreach my $file (@files){
  my $orig_file = $second_dir"/"$file;
  print $orig_file . "\n";
```

}

`
but 
    my $orig_file = $second_dir"/"$file;
does not work,

how can I assem ble a full path presentation of my file in the second dir?

thanks
Shahar

Comment: May be you could have a look at: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html

Answer (score 2):

You either need to do string interpolation or concatenation.

- `my $orig_file = "$second_dir/$file";         # Interpolated variables`
- `my $orig_file = $second_dir . "/" . $file;   # Concatenated variables`

Note, be sure to include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY script.  Additionally, be sure to include [`use autodie;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) anytime you're doing file or directory processing.

The following is a clean up of your script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $first_dir = '....';
my $second_dir = '....';

open my $dh, $first_dir;
while (my $file = <$dh>) {
    my $orig_file = "$second_dir/$file";
    print $orig_file . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my $orig_file = $second_dir"/"$file; #<-- wrong
```

you should write:

```
my $orig_file = $second_dir . "/" . $file;
```

or this:

```
my $orig_file = "$second_dir/$file";
```